# How to assign arrow and enter keyboard keys in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need your help with being able to finish my tally counter programme written in hTML and JavaScript. Please help me to get know what is the **most simple way** to assign the up and down arrow and Enter keyboard keys for increase, decrease and reset numbers my tally counter? Thanks for your help in advance.

I have this code in HTML and JavaScript where the buttons work right and properly but I cannot add the keyboard keys mentioned above.

```js
let add = document.getElementById("increment");
let remove = document.getElementById("decrement");
let reset = document.getElementById("reset");

let int = document.getElementById("number");
let integer = 0;

add.addEventListener('click', function(){
    integer += 1;
    int.innerHTML = integer
})

remove.addEventListener('click', function(){
    integer -= 1;
    int.innerHTML = integer
})

reset.addEventListener('click', function(){
    integer = 0;
    int.innerHTML = integer
})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#container {
    width: 246px;
    height: 187px;
    background-color: #F7CF5B;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-left: 25px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 4px solid #09AA20;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

#number {
    background-color: #19A709;
    width: 77%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 3px solid #FF2600;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 8px;
    }

#title {
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 33px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-left: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#increment {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #09AA20;
    text-align: center;
}

#decrement {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #0226F9;
}

#reset {
    width: 60px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 1px;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Tally Counter 1.0</title>
<link href="CSS/counter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        background-color: #7B1A1A;
    }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
  <div id="title">Tally Counter</div>
  <div id="number">0</div>
  <button id="increment">+1</button>
  <button id="decrement">-1</button>
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>

<script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
    
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hint: On key down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an eventListener on the document and listen for a `keydown` event. On `keydown` check the `event.key` entry and if it is set to the desired key, run the desired code; add, subtract or reset your value. A switch conditional may be better suited for this application as well.

```js
let add = document.getElementById("increment");
let remove = document.getElementById("decrement");
let reset = document.getElementById("reset");





let int = document.getElementById("number");
let integer = 0;

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === "ArrowUp") {
    integer++;
  } else if (e.key === "ArrowDown") {
    integer--;
  } else if (e.key === "Enter") {
    integer = 0;
  }
  int.textContent = integer;
});

add.addEventListener('click', function() {
  integer += 1;
  int.innerHTML = integer
})



remove.addEventListener('click', function() {
  integer -= 1;
  int.innerHTML = integer
})

reset.addEventListener('click', function() {
  integer = 0;
  int.innerHTML = integer
})
```

```css
@charset "utf-8";
#container {
  width: 246px;
  height: 187px;
  background-color: #F7CF5B;
  padding-top: 4px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 4px solid #09AA20;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#number {
  background-color: #19A709;
  width: 77%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #FF2600;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 8px;
}

#title {
  color: #FF0000;
  font-size: 33px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#increment {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #09AA20;
  text-align: center;
}

#decrement {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #0226F9;
}

#reset {
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  padding-right: 1px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  padding-left: 1px;
  margin-top: 11px;
  margin-left: 9px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #252525;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Tally Counter 1.0</title>
  <link href="CSS/counter.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #7B1A1A;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div id="container">
    <div id="title">Tally Counter</div>
    <div id="number">0</div>
    <button id="increment">+1</button>
    <button id="decrement">-1</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>

    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am happy now because the code is working properly. Greetings from Hungary. 

(I am a disabled man sitting in wheelchair since I was born. I am a beginner user here and it was my first question and I hope I will be able to find the way to give you a positive vote for your answer here.)